# How can I replace parameter by subdirectory

Tags: web, nginx, host

Currently I have my search page hosted like below

```
mywebsite.com/search.html?query=cat
```

So I am extracting query from url parameter as you can see the query is `'cat'` for now.

 For some seo reasons this is not a good practice so I want to replace above format to following format:

```
mywebsite.com/search/cat
```

Is there any way to achieve such result without actually changing the current files? Right now I am hosting the website with `nginx` in `ubuntu` server. Any suggestion is hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the following rewrite in your NGINX configuration (in `server {...}` block):

```
rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /search.html?query=$1 last;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is redirecting me to the previous url.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of examples for this in SO.

Nevertheless here is a suggestion:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^/?search/(.+)/?$ /search.html?query=cat [END,QSA]

RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=(.*)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?search\.html$ /search/%1 [R=301]
```

Comment: The question is for nginx server.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Sorry, I missed that, indeed the question contradicts itself. It is _explicitly_ tagged `.htaccess`...